How to add a variable to a dataframe which is defined in a different dataframe
I have two dataframes and need to pick out information from one to add to the other. My original dataframe has >300.000 rows. It has a variable called var_z that can have over 300 different values. According to the value of var_z an additional column ("new_variable") will be added to the dataframe. The value of new_variable is stored in a much shorter dataframe ("key_df") which relates the var_z to new_variable.
My aim is to add the column new_variable to the original dataframe in an efficient way.
Let's downscale this a bit to show you what I've done so far.
# Create the dataframe to which I want to add the new_variable
var_x <- c(1:21)
var_z <- c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,15,15,15,15,15,15,15)
value <- c(5.80,5.80,5.84,5.88,5.88,5.81,5.80,5.66,5.55,5.49,5.46,5.48,5.48,5.46,5.40,5.39,5.39,5.66,5.55,5.49,5.46)
example_df <- data.frame(var_x,var_z,value)

# create the dataframe that gives the actual value of new_variable
var_z <- c(3,9,15)
new_variable <- c(0.88325, 0.834945,0.80273 )
key_df <- data.frame(var_z,new_variable)

# look up the value of new_variable and add it to the first dataframe
example_df$new_variable <- ifelse(example_df$var_z == key_df$var_z[1], key_df$new_variable[1],
                           ifelse(example_df$var_z == key_df$var_z[2], key_df$new_variable[2],
                              key_df$new_variable[3]))

So, this basically does what I want it to do, but regarding the size of the actual dataframes it is not a solution. How can I do that, possibly using a loop or sapply? Would a hashmap be a solution? I understand it stores key-value pairs but I haven't been able to figure out how to actually use it and if it would be an option in this case.

merge(example_df, key_df, by = c("var_z"), all.x = TRUE), or with library(dplyr) you can do left_join(example_df, key_df, by = "var_z"), which will probably be a little speedier if your data is large.

Typically this is called a "join" and is fundamental concept in working with data. You may want to check out a resource on joins, such as the relevant chapter in R For Data Science.
